# Jersey 2.4 ReaderInterceptor is not working

Tags: java, httprequest, jersey-2.0

I'm testing Jersey interceptors and filters. I have this Jersey 2.4 interceptor code:

```
@Provider
@Test
public class TestInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor, ReaderInterceptor {
    private final static Logger log = ....

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo (WriterInterceptorContext context) 
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        log.debug("WriterInterceptor");
        context.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext ric) 
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        log.debug("ReaderInterceptor");
        return ric.proceed();
    }    
}
```

my resource method:

```
@Path("{test}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Test
public FooObj test () {
    log.debug("test method");
    return new FooObj();
}
```

two filters:

```
@Provider
public class ResponseFil implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private final static Logger log = ....

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc, ContainerResponseContext crc1)
        throws IOException {
        log.debug("ResponseFil");
    }
}

@Provider
public class RequestFil implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final static Logger log = ....
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {
        log.debug("RequestFil");
    }
}
```

and my web.xml servlet configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <description>Servlet test</description>
    <servlet-name>REST_servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

When from firefox I type the url address resource and get the result, log console shows:

```
RequestFil
test method
ResponseFil
WriterInterceptor
```

Why ReaderInterceptor isn't executed? I have tried to separate write and reader interceptors in two classes with two custom binding names (@Test and @Test2) with the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Interceptors (implementations of [ReaderInterceptor](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) / [WriterInterceptor](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html)) are executed only if request/response entity is available. In your case this means that only `WriterInterceptor` is being executed since you're sending entity (an instance of `FooObj`) to the client from your resource method. If you had a `POST` method that receives an input from user your `ReaderInterceptor` would be invoked as well.

In case you need to modify the request even if no entity is present use [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) / [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html).

See [JAX-RS 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) spec for more info.